# Is there a way to declare "give me everything in extras_require"?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Say I have the following in a python setup.py

```
setup(
    name='mypkg',
    extras_require={'foo': ['pkg1'], 'bar': ['pkg2'],
                    'baz': ['pkg1', 'pkg3']},
    ...
)
```

Is there a standard or convention meaning give-me-everything?

I know about `pip install mypkg[foo,bar,baz]`

Is there anything like `pip install mypkg[*]` (just an example, I know it doesn't work), or a naming convention in setup.py like `extras_require={..., 'full': <requirements for foo,bar,baz>}`?